# How to connect an Eero Pro 6e router to a network switch?

Tags: networking, router, switch, wireless-networking, modem

I have a basement home lab and I wish to connect my router to my network switch.

I have the [Arris S33](https://www.surfboard.com/products/cable-modems/s33/) modem and the [Eero Pro 6e](https://eero.com/shop/eero-pro-6e) for the router. The switch is a [YuanLey YS25-0402](https://yuanley.com/products/yuanley-6-port-25g-poe-switch-unmanaged,-4-x-25g-base-t-poe-ports,-2-x-10g-sfp,-ieee8023af-at,-78w,-compatible-with-100-1000-2500mbps,-metal-fanless,-desktop-wall-mount-25gbe-network-switch) 6 port 2.5G unmanaged ethernet switch.

I have the incoming connection from my ISP running into my modem which is downstairs, I then have a Cat 6e cable running upstairs to the first Eero Pro 6e in my living room which connects to everything for my family and I.

The current setup looks like this:

> ISP Connection => Modem => Eero Pro 6e

None of the things I have in the basement are connected at the moment because I have no means of doing so.

I wish to have things connected like this:

> ISP Connection => Modem => Network Switch => Eero Pro 6e

All of my devices downstairs (Server, Printers, etc) I wish to connect to the switch as well as the Eero. I don't really mind those devices being within scope of the Wi-Fi network. It would be a plus but not really necessary.

It is my understanding that I need to disable DHCP on the router for it to function when plugged into the switch. Is this correct?

And how do I assign a static IP using the Eero? Their app is useful but to a certain degree.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149729/discussion-on-question-by-riley-richard-how-to-connect-an-eero-pro-6e-router-to); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting a switch to a cable modem](https://superuser.com/questions/1122793/connecting-a-switch-to-a-cable-modem)